# vernemq cluster node terminate due to remote_node_not_available

Tags: mqtt-vernemq

I am trying to setup vernemq cluster on Kubernetes using StatefulSet. Following is my manifest file.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: vernemq
  namespace: dev-ethernet
data:
  vernemq.conf: |
    accept_eula = yes
    plugins.vmq_passwd = off
    plugins.vmq_acl = off
    allow_anonymous = on
    max_client_id_size = 100
    max_inflight_messages = 0
    max_online_messages = 1000
    message_size_limit = 0
    listener.max_connections = 10000
    listener.tcp.default = 127.0.0.1:1883
    listener.ssl.default = 127.0.0.1:8883
    listener.vmq.clustering = 0.0.0.0:44053
    erlang.distribution.port_range.minimum = 9100
    erlang.distribution.port_range.maximum = 9109
    listener.ssl.require_certificate = on
    listener.ssl.cafile = /vernemq/cert/ca.crt
    listener.ssl.certfile = /vernemq/cert/server.crt
    listener.ssl.keyfile = /vernemq/cert/server.key
    listener.ssl.tls_version = tlsv1.2
    log.console = console
    log.console.level = debug

---

apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: vernemq
  namespace: dev-ethernet
  labels:
    app: vernemq
spec:
  serviceName: vernemq
  replicas: 2
  podManagementPolicy: OrderedReady
  updateStrategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: vernemq
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: vernemq
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: vernemq
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 60
      containers:
        - name: vernemq
          image: vernemq/vernemq:1.10.4.1
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          #restartPolicy: OnFailure
          ports:
            - name: mqtt
              containerPort: 1883
            - name: mqtts
              containerPort: 8883
            - name: epmd
              containerPort: 4369
            - name: vmq
              containerPort: 44053
            - name: metrics
              containerPort: 8888
            - containerPort: 9100
            - containerPort: 9101
            - containerPort: 9102
            - containerPort: 9103
            - containerPort: 9104
            - containerPort: 9105
            - containerPort: 9106
            - containerPort: 9107
            - containerPort: 9108
            - containerPort: 9109
          env:
            - name: MY_POD_NAME
              valueFrom:
                fieldRef:
                  fieldPath: metadata.name
            - name: MY_POD_IP
              valueFrom:
                fieldRef:
                  fieldPath: status.podIP
            - name: DOCKER_VERNEMQ_DISCOVERY_KUBERNETES
              value: "1"
            - name: DOCKER_VERNEMQ_KUBERNETES_LABEL_SELECTOR
              value: "app=vernemq"
          lifecycle:
            preStop:
              exec:
                command:
                - /bin/bash
                - -c
                - /usr/sbin/vmq-admin cluster leave node=VerneMQ@${MY_POD_NAME}.vernemq.${DOCKER_VERNEMQ_KUBERNETES_NAMESPACE}.svc.cluster.local ; sleep 1 ; /usr/sbin/vmq-admin cluster leave node=VerneMQ@${MY_POD_NAME}.vernemq.${DOCKER_VERNEMQ_KUBERNETES_NAMESPACE}.svc.cluster.local -k
          volumeMounts:
            - name: conf
              mountPath: /etc/vernemq/vernemq.conf
              subPath: vernemq.conf
            - name: data
              mountPath: /vernemq/data
            - name: cert
              mountPath: /vernemq/cert
      securityContext:
        runAsUser: 10000
        runAsGroup: 10000
        fsGroup: 10000
      volumes:
        - name: conf
          configMap:
            name: vernemq
        - name: cert
          secret:
            secretName: vernemq
  volumeClaimTemplates:
    - metadata:
        name: data
        labels:
          app: elasticsearch
      spec:
        accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
        storageClassName: aws-gp2
        resources:
          requests:
            storage: 5Gi
---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: vernemq
  namespace: dev-ethernet
  labels:
    app: vernemq
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  sessionAffinity: None
  ports:
    - name: mqtt
      port: 1883
      targetPort: mqtt
    - name: mqtts
      port: 8883
      targetPort: mqtts
  selector:
    app: vernemq

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: vernemq-headless
  namespace: dev-ethernet
  labels:
    app: vernemq
spec:
  clusterIP: None
  ports:
    - name: empd
      port: 4369
      targetPort: empd
    - name: metrics
      port: 8888
      targetPort: metrics
  selector:
    app: vernemq

---
```

When each vernemq pod starts I see following logs

```
sed: cannot rename /vernemq/etc/sedmHjPDJ: Device or resource busy
/usr/sbin/start_vernemq: line 85: /vernemq/etc/vernemq.conf: Permission denied
/usr/sbin/start_vernemq: line 87: /vernemq/etc/vernemq.conf: Permission denied
/usr/sbin/start_vernemq: line 104: /vernemq/etc/vernemq.conf: Permission denied
/usr/sbin/start_vernemq: line 105: /vernemq/etc/vernemq.conf: Permission denied
/usr/sbin/start_vernemq: line 106: /vernemq/etc/vernemq.conf: Permission denied
/usr/sbin/start_vernemq: line 107: /vernemq/etc/vernemq.conf: Permission denied
/usr/sbin/start_vernemq: line 108: /vernemq/etc/vernemq.conf: Permission denied
/usr/sbin/start_vernemq: line 109: /vernemq/etc/vernemq.conf: Permission denied
/usr/sbin/start_vernemq: line 111: /vernemq/etc/vernemq.conf: Permission denied
config is OK
-config /vernemq/data/generated.configs/app.2020.08.07.13.35.51.config -args_file /vernemq/bin/../etc/vm.args -vm_args /vernemq/bin/../etc/vm.args
Exec:  /vernemq/bin/../erts-10.7/bin/erlexec -boot /vernemq/bin/../releases/1.10.4.1/vernemq               -config /vernemq/data/generated.configs/app.2020.08.07.13.35.51.config -args_file /vernemq/bin/../etc/vm.args -vm_args /vernemq/bin/../etc/vm.args              -pa /vernemq/bin/../lib/erlio-patches -- console -noshell -noinput
Root: /vernemq/bin/..
13:35:53.195 [debug] Lager installed handler {lager_file_backend,"./log/error.log"} into lager_event
13:35:53.195 [debug] Lager installed handler error_logger_lager_h into error_logger
13:35:53.345 [info] alarm_handler: {set,{system_memory_high_watermark,[]}}
13:35:53.422 [info] read state from file {[{[{actor,<<54,23,183,142,204,71,5,136,102,104,80,216,237,50,98,197,34,16,158,224>>}],1}],{dict,1,16,16,8,80,48,{[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]},{{[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[['VerneMQ@10.100.6.18',{[{actor,<<54,23,183,142,204,71,5,136,102,104,80,216,237,50,98,197,34,16,158,224>>}],1}]],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]}}},{dict,0,16,16,8,80,48,{[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]},{{[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]}}}}
13:35:53.423 [info] writing state {[{[{actor,<<54,23,183,142,204,71,5,136,102,104,80,216,237,50,98,197,34,16,158,224>>}],1}],{dict,1,16,16,8,80,48,{[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]},{{[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[['VerneMQ@10.100.6.18',{[{actor,<<54,23,183,142,204,71,5,136,102,104,80,216,237,50,98,197,34,16,158,224>>}],1}]],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]}}},{dict,0,16,16,8,80,48,{[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]},{{[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]}}}} to disk <<75,2,131,80,0,0,0,249,120,1,203,96,206,97,96,96,96,204,96,130,82,41,12,172,137,201,37,249,69,185,64,81,17,51,241,237,125,103,220,89,59,210,50,2,110,188,53,74,58,170,36,48,239,65,86,34,99,86,6,103,10,3,75,74,102,114,73,34,99,162,0,16,114,36,6,36,26,100,8,100,161,129,12,70,132,24,216,120,16,193,148,194,32,28,150,90,148,151,234,27,232,96,104,160,103,104,96,160,103,166,103,104,65,154,3,96,22,33,28,194,64,172,67,96,90,1,27,43,76,93>>
13:35:53.438 [info] Datadir ./data/meta/meta/0 options for LevelDB: [{open,[{block_cache_threshold,33554432},{block_restart_interval,16},{block_size_steps,16},{compression,true},{create_if_missing,true},{delete_threshold,1000},{eleveldb_threads,71},{fadvise_willneed,false},{limited_developer_mem,false},{sst_block_size,4096},{tiered_slow_level,0},{total_leveldb_mem_percent,6},{use_bloomfilter,true},{write_buffer_size,38549145}]},{read,[{verify_checksums,true}]},{write,[{sync,false}]},{fold,[{verify_checksums,true},{fill_cache,false}]}]
13:35:53.445 [info] Datadir ./data/meta/meta/1 options for LevelDB: [{open,[{block_cache_threshold,33554432},{block_restart_interval,16},{block_size_steps,16},{compression,true},{create_if_missing,true},{delete_threshold,1000},{eleveldb_threads,71},{fadvise_willneed,false},{limited_developer_mem,false},{sst_block_size,4096},{tiered_slow_level,0},{total_leveldb_mem_percent,6},{use_bloomfilter,true},{write_buffer_size,35929523}]},{read,[{verify_checksums,true}]},{write,[{sync,false}]},{fold,[{verify_checksums,true},{fill_cache,false}]}]
13:35:53.452 [info] Datadir ./data/meta/meta/2 options for LevelDB: [{open,[{block_cache_threshold,33554432},{block_restart_interval,16},{block_size_steps,16},{compression,true},{create_if_missing,true},{delete_threshold,1000},{eleveldb_threads,71},{fadvise_willneed,false},{limited_developer_mem,false},{sst_block_size,4096},{tiered_slow_level,0},{total_leveldb_mem_percent,6},{use_bloomfilter,true},{write_buffer_size,31795161}]},{read,[{verify_checksums,true}]},{write,[{sync,false}]},{fold,[{verify_checksums,true},{fill_cache,false}]}]
13:35:53.459 [info] Datadir ./data/meta/meta/3 options for LevelDB: [{open,[{block_cache_threshold,33554432},{block_restart_interval,16},{block_size_steps,16},{compression,true},{create_if_missing,true},{delete_threshold,1000},{eleveldb_threads,71},{fadvise_willneed,false},{limited_developer_mem,false},{sst_block_size,4096},{tiered_slow_level,0},{total_leveldb_mem_percent,6},{use_bloomfilter,true},{write_buffer_size,52387290}]},{read,[{verify_checksums,true}]},{write,[{sync,false}]},{fold,[{verify_checksums,true},{fill_cache,false}]}]
13:35:53.467 [info] Datadir ./data/meta/meta/4 options for LevelDB: [{open,[{block_cache_threshold,33554432},{block_restart_interval,16},{block_size_steps,16},{compression,true},{create_if_missing,true},{delete_threshold,1000},{eleveldb_threads,71},{fadvise_willneed,false},{limited_developer_mem,false},{sst_block_size,4096},{tiered_slow_level,0},{total_leveldb_mem_percent,6},{use_bloomfilter,true},{write_buffer_size,35280518}]},{read,[{verify_checksums,true}]},{write,[{sync,false}]},{fold,[{verify_checksums,true},{fill_cache,false}]}]
13:35:53.475 [info] Datadir ./data/meta/meta/5 options for LevelDB: [{open,[{block_cache_threshold,33554432},{block_restart_interval,16},{block_size_steps,16},{compression,true},{create_if_missing,true},{delete_threshold,1000},{eleveldb_threads,71},{fadvise_willneed,false},{limited_developer_mem,false},{sst_block_size,4096},{tiered_slow_level,0},{total_leveldb_mem_percent,6},{use_bloomfilter,true},{write_buffer_size,60988348}]},{read,[{verify_checksums,true}]},{write,[{sync,false}]},{fold,[{verify_checksums,true},{fill_cache,false}]}]
13:35:53.483 [info] Datadir ./data/meta/meta/6 options for LevelDB: [{open,[{block_cache_threshold,33554432},{block_restart_interval,16},{block_size_steps,16},{compression,true},{create_if_missing,true},{delete_threshold,1000},{eleveldb_threads,71},{fadvise_willneed,false},{limited_developer_mem,false},{sst_block_size,4096},{tiered_slow_level,0},{total_leveldb_mem_percent,6},{use_bloomfilter,true},{write_buffer_size,43175699}]},{read,[{verify_checksums,true}]},{write,[{sync,false}]},{fold,[{verify_checksums,true},{fill_cache,false}]}]
13:35:53.502 [info] Datadir ./data/meta/meta/7 options for LevelDB: [{open,[{block_cache_threshold,33554432},{block_restart_interval,16},{block_size_steps,16},{compression,true},{create_if_missing,true},{delete_threshold,1000},{eleveldb_threads,71},{fadvise_willneed,false},{limited_developer_mem,false},{sst_block_size,4096},{tiered_slow_level,0},{total_leveldb_mem_percent,6},{use_bloomfilter,true},{write_buffer_size,35409215}]},{read,[{verify_checksums,true}]},{write,[{sync,false}]},{fold,[{verify_checksums,true},{fill_cache,false}]}]
13:35:53.509 [info] Datadir ./data/meta/meta/8 options for LevelDB: [{open,[{block_cache_threshold,33554432},{block_restart_interval,16},{block_size_steps,16},{compression,true},{create_if_missing,true},{delete_threshold,1000},{eleveldb_threads,71},{fadvise_willneed,false},{limited_developer_mem,false},{sst_block_size,4096},{tiered_slow_level,0},{total_leveldb_mem_percent,6},{use_bloomfilter,true},{write_buffer_size,51476514}]},{read,[{verify_checksums,true}]},{write,[{sync,false}]},{fold,[{verify_checksums,true},{fill_cache,false}]}]
13:35:53.516 [info] Datadir ./data/meta/meta/9 options for LevelDB: [{open,[{block_cache_threshold,33554432},{block_restart_interval,16},{block_size_steps,16},{compression,true},{create_if_missing,true},{delete_threshold,1000},{eleveldb_threads,71},{fadvise_willneed,false},{limited_developer_mem,false},{sst_block_size,4096},{tiered_slow_level,0},{total_leveldb_mem_percent,6},{use_bloomfilter,true},{write_buffer_size,62879451}]},{read,[{verify_checksums,true}]},{write,[{sync,false}]},{fold,[{verify_checksums,true},{fill_cache,false}]}]
13:35:53.523 [info] Datadir ./data/meta/meta/10 options for LevelDB: [{open,[{block_cache_threshold,33554432},{block_restart_interval,16},{block_size_steps,16},{compression,true},{create_if_missing,true},{delete_threshold,1000},{eleveldb_threads,71},{fadvise_willneed,false},{limited_developer_mem,false},{sst_block_size,4096},{tiered_slow_level,0},{total_leveldb_mem_percent,6},{use_bloomfilter,true},{write_buffer_size,54094689}]},{read,[{verify_checksums,true}]},{write,[{sync,false}]},{fold,[{verify_checksums,true},{fill_cache,false}]}]
13:35:53.530 [info] Datadir ./data/meta/meta/11 options for LevelDB: [{open,[{block_cache_threshold,33554432},{block_restart_interval,16},{block_size_steps,16},{compression,true},{create_if_missing,true},{delete_threshold,1000},{eleveldb_threads,71},{fadvise_willneed,false},{limited_developer_mem,false},{sst_block_size,4096},{tiered_slow_level,0},{total_leveldb_mem_percent,6},{use_bloomfilter,true},{write_buffer_size,54172211}]},{read,[{verify_checksums,true}]},{write,[{sync,false}]},{fold,[{verify_checksums,true},{fill_cache,false}]}]
13:35:53.550 [debug] 0ms mailbox traversal, schedule next lazy broadcast in 10000ms, the min interval is 10000ms
13:35:53.577 [debug] loading modules: [vmq_plumtree,vmq_plumtree_app,vmq_plumtree_sup]
13:35:53.603 [info] Try to start vmq_plumtree: ok
13:35:53.637 [debug] datadir ./data/msgstore/1 options for LevelDB: [{open,[{block_cache_threshold,33554432},{block_restart_interval,16},{block_size_steps,16},{compression,true},{create_if_missing,true},{delete_threshold,1000},{eleveldb_threads,71},{fadvise_willneed,false},{limited_developer_mem,false},{sst_block_size,4096},{tiered_slow_level,0},{total_leveldb_mem_percent,70},{use_bloomfilter,true},{write_buffer_size,47750847}]},{read,[{verify_checksums,true}]},{write,[{sync,false}]},{fold,[{verify_checksums,true},{fill_cache,false}]}]
13:35:53.645 [info] Opening LevelDB database at "./data/msgstore/1"
13:35:53.646 [debug] datadir ./data/msgstore/2 options for LevelDB: [{open,[{block_cache_threshold,33554432},{block_restart_interval,16},{block_size_steps,16},{compression,true},{create_if_missing,true},{delete_threshold,1000},{eleveldb_threads,71},{fadvise_willneed,false},{limited_developer_mem,false},{sst_block_size,4096},{tiered_slow_level,0},{total_leveldb_mem_percent,70},{use_bloomfilter,true},{write_buffer_size,50090150}]},{read,[{verify_checksums,true}]},{write,[{sync,false}]},{fold,[{verify_checksums,true},{fill_cache,false}]}]
13:35:53.653 [info] Opening LevelDB database at "./data/msgstore/2"
13:35:53.653 [debug] datadir ./data/msgstore/3 options for LevelDB: [{open,[{block_cache_threshold,33554432},{block_restart_interval,16},{block_size_steps,16},{compression,true},{create_if_missing,true},{delete_threshold,1000},{eleveldb_threads,71},{fadvise_willneed,false},{limited_developer_mem,false},{sst_block_size,4096},{tiered_slow_level,0},{total_leveldb_mem_percent,70},{use_bloomfilter,true},{write_buffer_size,34848743}]},{read,[{verify_checksums,true}]},{write,[{sync,false}]},{fold,[{verify_checksums,true},{fill_cache,false}]}]
13:35:53.660 [info] Opening LevelDB database at "./data/msgstore/3"
13:35:53.661 [debug] datadir ./data/msgstore/4 options for LevelDB: [{open,[{block_cache_threshold,33554432},{block_restart_interval,16},{block_size_steps,16},{compression,true},{create_if_missing,true},{delete_threshold,1000},{eleveldb_threads,71},{fadvise_willneed,false},{limited_developer_mem,false},{sst_block_size,4096},{tiered_slow_level,0},{total_leveldb_mem_percent,70},{use_bloomfilter,true},{write_buffer_size,41593831}]},{read,[{verify_checksums,true}]},{write,[{sync,false}]},{fold,[{verify_checksums,true},{fill_cache,false}]}]
13:35:53.667 [info] Opening LevelDB database at "./data/msgstore/4"
13:35:53.668 [debug] datadir ./data/msgstore/5 options for LevelDB: [{open,[{block_cache_threshold,33554432},{block_restart_interval,16},{block_size_steps,16},{compression,true},{create_if_missing,true},{delete_threshold,1000},{eleveldb_threads,71},{fadvise_willneed,false},{limited_developer_mem,false},{sst_block_size,4096},{tiered_slow_level,0},{total_leveldb_mem_percent,70},{use_bloomfilter,true},{write_buffer_size,45767049}]},{read,[{verify_checksums,true}]},{write,[{sync,false}]},{fold,[{verify_checksums,true},{fill_cache,false}]}]
13:35:53.674 [info] Opening LevelDB database at "./data/msgstore/5"
13:35:53.675 [debug] datadir ./data/msgstore/6 options for LevelDB: [{open,[{block_cache_threshold,33554432},{block_restart_interval,16},{block_size_steps,16},{compression,true},{create_if_missing,true},{delete_threshold,1000},{eleveldb_threads,71},{fadvise_willneed,false},{limited_developer_mem,false},{sst_block_size,4096},{tiered_slow_level,0},{total_leveldb_mem_percent,70},{use_bloomfilter,true},{write_buffer_size,56785000}]},{read,[{verify_checksums,true}]},{write,[{sync,false}]},{fold,[{verify_checksums,true},{fill_cache,false}]}]
13:35:53.681 [info] Opening LevelDB database at "./data/msgstore/6"
13:35:53.682 [debug] datadir ./data/msgstore/7 options for LevelDB: [{open,[{block_cache_threshold,33554432},{block_restart_interval,16},{block_size_steps,16},{compression,true},{create_if_missing,true},{delete_threshold,1000},{eleveldb_threads,71},{fadvise_willneed,false},{limited_developer_mem,false},{sst_block_size,4096},{tiered_slow_level,0},{total_leveldb_mem_percent,70},{use_bloomfilter,true},{write_buffer_size,60588967}]},{read,[{verify_checksums,true}]},{write,[{sync,false}]},{fold,[{verify_checksums,true},{fill_cache,false}]}]
13:35:53.683 [debug] Lager installed handler lager_backend_throttle into lager_event
13:35:53.688 [info] Opening LevelDB database at "./data/msgstore/7"
13:35:53.689 [debug] datadir ./data/msgstore/8 options for LevelDB: [{open,[{block_cache_threshold,33554432},{block_restart_interval,16},{block_size_steps,16},{compression,true},{create_if_missing,true},{delete_threshold,1000},{eleveldb_threads,71},{fadvise_willneed,false},{limited_developer_mem,false},{sst_block_size,4096},{tiered_slow_level,0},{total_leveldb_mem_percent,70},{use_bloomfilter,true},{write_buffer_size,41872335}]},{read,[{verify_checksums,true}]},{write,[{sync,false}]},{fold,[{verify_checksums,true},{fill_cache,false}]}]
13:35:53.695 [info] Opening LevelDB database at "./data/msgstore/8"
13:35:53.696 [debug] datadir ./data/msgstore/9 options for LevelDB: [{open,[{block_cache_threshold,33554432},{block_restart_interval,16},{block_size_steps,16},{compression,true},{create_if_missing,true},{delete_threshold,1000},{eleveldb_threads,71},{fadvise_willneed,false},{limited_developer_mem,false},{sst_block_size,4096},{tiered_slow_level,0},{total_leveldb_mem_percent,70},{use_bloomfilter,true},{write_buffer_size,35898829}]},{read,[{verify_checksums,true}]},{write,[{sync,false}]},{fold,[{verify_checksums,true},{fill_cache,false}]}]
13:35:53.703 [info] Opening LevelDB database at "./data/msgstore/9"
13:35:53.703 [debug] datadir ./data/msgstore/10 options for LevelDB: [{open,[{block_cache_threshold,33554432},{block_restart_interval,16},{block_size_steps,16},{compression,true},{create_if_missing,true},{delete_threshold,1000},{eleveldb_threads,71},{fadvise_willneed,false},{limited_developer_mem,false},{sst_block_size,4096},{tiered_slow_level,0},{total_leveldb_mem_percent,70},{use_bloomfilter,true},{write_buffer_size,47214115}]},{read,[{verify_checksums,true}]},{write,[{sync,false}]},{fold,[{verify_checksums,true},{fill_cache,false}]}]
13:35:53.710 [info] Opening LevelDB database at "./data/msgstore/10"
13:35:53.711 [debug] datadir ./data/msgstore/11 options for LevelDB: [{open,[{block_cache_threshold,33554432},{block_restart_interval,16},{block_size_steps,16},{compression,true},{create_if_missing,true},{delete_threshold,1000},{eleveldb_threads,71},{fadvise_willneed,false},{limited_developer_mem,false},{sst_block_size,4096},{tiered_slow_level,0},{total_leveldb_mem_percent,70},{use_bloomfilter,true},{write_buffer_size,36069724}]},{read,[{verify_checksums,true}]},{write,[{sync,false}]},{fold,[{verify_checksums,true},{fill_cache,false}]}]
13:35:53.719 [info] Opening LevelDB database at "./data/msgstore/11"
13:35:53.720 [debug] datadir ./data/msgstore/12 options for LevelDB: [{open,[{block_cache_threshold,33554432},{block_restart_interval,16},{block_size_steps,16},{compression,true},{create_if_missing,true},{delete_threshold,1000},{eleveldb_threads,71},{fadvise_willneed,false},{limited_developer_mem,false},{sst_block_size,4096},{tiered_slow_level,0},{total_leveldb_mem_percent,70},{use_bloomfilter,true},{write_buffer_size,56905298}]},{read,[{verify_checksums,true}]},{write,[{sync,false}]},{fold,[{verify_checksums,true},{fill_cache,false}]}]
13:35:53.730 [info] Opening LevelDB database at "./data/msgstore/12"
13:35:53.730 [debug] loading modules: [vmq_generic_msg_store,vmq_generic_msg_store_app,vmq_generic_msg_store_sup,vmq_generic_msg_store_utils,vmq_storage_engine_dets,vmq_storage_engine_ets,vmq_storage_engine_leveldb]
13:35:53.767 [info] Try to start vmq_generic_msg_store: ok
13:35:53.770 [info] rename VerneMQ node from 'VerneMQ@10.100.6.18' to 'VerneMQ@10.100.6.34'
13:35:53.773 [info] writing state {[{[{actor,<<54,23,183,142,204,71,5,136,102,104,80,216,237,50,98,197,34,16,158,224>>}],1},{<<105,153,35,109,220,173,228,160,165,82,37,54,41,250,215,10,226,156,138,159>>,1}],{dict,1,16,16,8,80,48,{[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]},{{[],[],[],[],[['VerneMQ@10.100.6.34',{<<105,153,35,109,220,173,228,160,165,82,37,54,41,250,215,10,226,156,138,159>>,1}]],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]}}},{dict,0,16,16,8,80,48,{[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]},{{[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]}}}} to disk <<75,2,131,80,0,0,1,6,120,1,203,96,206,97,96,96,96,202,96,2,81,140,25,76,41,12,172,137,201,37,249,69,185,64,174,136,153,248,246,190,51,238,172,29,105,25,1,55,222,26,37,29,85,18,152,247,32,43,17,168,10,44,155,57,83,57,247,206,218,39,11,150,6,169,154,105,254,186,206,245,104,78,215,252,68,198,172,12,206,20,6,150,148,204,228,146,68,198,68,1,32,228,72,12,72,52,200,16,200,66,3,25,140,16,49,176,189,96,55,164,48,8,135,165,22,229,165,250,6,58,24,26,232,25,26,24,232,153,233,25,155,224,183,12,217,80,132,197,12,196,88,140,172,21,0,76,92,86,0>>
13:35:53.868 [info] loaded 0 subscriptions into vmq_reg_trie
13:35:53.872 [info] cluster event handler 'vmq_cluster' registered
.
.
.
15:10:21.166 [debug] connect request from unknown cluster node 'VerneMQ@vernemq-1.vernemq.dev-ethernet.svc.cluster.local'
15:10:21.166 [warning] terminate due to remote_node_not_available
15:10:21.166 [warning] connection to node 'VerneMQ@vernemq-0.vernemq.dev-ethernet.svc.cluster.local' has been closed, reconnect in 1000ms
15:10:22.168 [info] successfully connected to cluster node 'VerneMQ@vernemq-0.vernemq.dev-ethernet.svc.cluster.local'
15:10:22.171 [debug] connect request from unknown cluster node 'VerneMQ@vernemq-1.vernemq.dev-ethernet.svc.cluster.local'
15:10:22.171 [warning] terminate due to remote_node_not_available
15:10:22.171 [warning] connection to node 'VerneMQ@vernemq-0.vernemq.dev-ethernet.svc.cluster.local' has been closed, reconnect in 1000ms
15:10:23.174 [info] successfully connected to cluster node 'VerneMQ@vernemq-0.vernemq.dev-ethernet.svc.cluster.local'
15:10:23.175 [debug] connect request from unknown cluster node 'VerneMQ@vernemq-1.vernemq.dev-ethernet.svc.cluster.local'
15:10:23.175 [warning] terminate due to remote_node_not_available
15:10:23.175 [warning] connection to node 'VerneMQ@vernemq-0.vernemq.dev-ethernet.svc.cluster.local' has been closed, reconnect in 1000ms
15:10:24.178 [info] successfully connected to cluster node 'VerneMQ@vernemq-0.vernemq.dev-ethernet.svc.cluster.local'
15:10:24.181 [debug] connect request from unknown cluster node 'VerneMQ@vernemq-1.vernemq.dev-ethernet.svc.cluster.local'
15:10:24.181 [warning] terminate due to remote_node_not_available
15:10:24.181 [warning] connection to node 'VerneMQ@vernemq-0.vernemq.dev-ethernet.svc.cluster.local' has been closed, reconnect in 1000ms
15:10:24.855 [debug] started plumtree_metadata_manager exchange with 'VerneMQ@vernemq-0.vernemq.dev-ethernet.svc.cluster.local' (<0.7531.0>)
15:10:24.864 [debug] completed metadata exchange with 'VerneMQ@vernemq-0.vernemq.dev-ethernet.svc.cluster.local'. nothing repaired
15:10:24.874 [debug] 0ms mailbox traversal, schedule next lazy broadcast in 10000ms, the min interval is 10000ms
15:10:25.183 [info] successfully connected to cluster node 'VerneMQ@vernemq-0.vernemq.dev-ethernet.svc.cluster.local'
15:10:25.184 [debug] connect request from unknown cluster node 'VerneMQ@vernemq-1.vernemq.dev-ethernet.svc.cluster.local'
15:10:25.184 [warning] terminate due to remote_node_not_available
15:10:25.184 [warning] connection to node 'VerneMQ@vernemq-0.vernemq.dev-ethernet.svc.cluster.local' has been closed, reconnect in 1000ms
15:10:26.187 [info] successfully connected to cluster node 'VerneMQ@vernemq-0.vernemq.dev-ethernet.svc.cluster.local'
15:10:26.187 [debug] connect request from unknown cluster node 'VerneMQ@vernemq-1.vernemq.dev-ethernet.svc.cluster.local'
15:10:26.187 [warning] terminate due to remote_node_not_available
15:10:26.187 [warning] connection to node 'VerneMQ@vernemq-0.vernemq.dev-ethernet.svc.cluster.local' has been closed, reconnect in 1000ms
15:10:27.190 [info] successfully connected to cluster node 'VerneMQ@vernemq-0.vernemq.dev-ethernet.svc.cluster.local'
15:10:27.190 [debug] connect request from unknown cluster node 'VerneMQ@vernemq-1.vernemq.dev-ethernet.svc.cluster.local'
15:10:27.190 [warning] terminate due to remote_node_not_available
15:10:27.190 [warning] connection to node 'VerneMQ@vernemq-0.vernemq.dev-ethernet.svc.cluster.local' has been closed, reconnect in 1000ms
```

cluster status looks good

```
vernemq@vernemq-0:~$ vmq-admin cluster show
+----------------------------------------------------------+---------+
| Node                                                     | Running |
+----------------------------------------------------------+---------+
| VerneMQ@vernemq-0.vernemq.dev-ethernet.svc.cluster.local | true    |
+----------------------------------------------------------+---------+
| VerneMQ@vernemq-1.vernemq.dev-ethernet.svc.cluster.local | true    |
+----------------------------------------------------------+---------+
```

But I am concerned about

```
15:10:27.190 [warning] terminate due to remote_node_not_available
15:10:27.190 [warning] connection to node 'VerneMQ@vernemq-0.vernemq.dev-ethernet.svc.cluster.local' has been closed, reconnect in 1000ms
```

Whats is causing nodes in cluster to disconnect ? or is it normal behavior ?

Comment: Somehow vernemq is sensitive to get configuration from configmap, i deleted configmap and it work. I will check how we can make it work with configmap.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not normal behaviour.

The reason this happens is that your nodes cannot reach each other for the TCP connections needed to exchange messages. (They can reach each other on the Erlang EPMD ports, that's why you see a cluster formed).

Look into this: `listener.vmq.clustering = 0.0.0.0:44053`. This port needs to be reachable, and maybe here the '0.0.0.0' causes your issue.

Comment: What I need to change here to fix this ?

Comment: I can't tell you what you need to change. I suppose this is Kubernetes with some cloud provider. Try to get clarity what is exposed on which network interfaces. lo, eth0, eth1.